# How i can print this array in php ? is it possible to print this array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have to print all the values present in array, as you can see this array contains multidimensional array as well as associative array as well.

```
$array = [1,2,[3 => [3 => [4,5,6,[7,8,[9=>[10,11,12,13],14=>15],16=>[17,18,19=>20]]]]]];
```

output should be like:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
OR
to print each and every element

Comment: There are many ways to print that array. Without knowing what your expected output looks like, it's very difficult to answer. Please [edit] your question to indicate how you want the array displayed.

Comment: @Nick sorry for the confusing question

Comment: That looks like you want to print *some* of the keys but *all* of the values. How do you decide which keys to print. For example, the only way to get a `3` is to print one of `3` keys, however there are multiple `0`,`1` and `2` keys, none of which appear to be printed.

Comment: implement recursive method

Answer (score 0):

This function that I called `magic` can solve your problem:

```php
function magic($array) {
    $indexCounter = 0;
    foreach ($array as $elementIndex => $elementValue) {
        if (is_array($elementValue)) {
            if ($indexCounter != $elementIndex) {
                echo $elementIndex;
            }
            magic($elementValue);
        } else {
            $arrayIndex = array_search($elementValue, $array);
            if ($indexCounter == $arrayIndex) {
                echo $elementValue;
            } else {
                echo $arrayIndex;
                echo $elementValue;
            }
        }
        $indexCounter ++;
    }
}
```

#### examples

```php
$array = [1,2,[3=>[4=>[5,6]]]];

magic($array);

function magic($array) {
    $indexCounter = 0;
    foreach ($array as $elementIndex => $elementValue) {
        if (is_array($elementValue)) {
            if ($indexCounter != $elementIndex) {
                echo $elementIndex;
            }
            magic($elementValue);
        } else {
            $arrayIndex = array_search($elementValue, $array);
            if ($indexCounter == $arrayIndex) {
                echo $elementValue;
            } else {
                echo $arrayIndex;
                echo $elementValue;
            }
        }
        $indexCounter ++;
    }
}
```

Output

```
123456
```

**And your exmaple**

```php
$array = [1,2,[3 => [3 => [4,5,6,[7,8,[9=>[10,11,12,13],14=>15],16=>[17,18,19=>20]]]]]];

magic($array);

function magic($array) {
    $indexCounter = 0;
    foreach ($array as $elementIndex => $elementValue) {
        if (is_array($elementValue)) {
            if ($indexCounter != $elementIndex) {
                echo $elementIndex;
            }
            magic($elementValue);
        } else {
            $arrayIndex = array_search($elementValue, $array);
            if ($indexCounter == $arrayIndex) {
                echo $elementValue;
            } else {
                echo $arrayIndex;
                echo $elementValue;
            }
        }
        $indexCounter ++;
    }
}
```

Output

```
12334567891011121314151617181920
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```php
$array = [
    1,
    2,
    [ 3 => [ 3 => [ 4, 5, 6, [ 7, 8, [ 9 => [ 10, 11, 12, 13 ], 14 => 15 ], 16 => [ 17, 18, 19 => 20 ] ] ] ] ],
];
$out = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function ($v) use (&$out) {
        $out[] = $v;
    }
);

echo implode(', ', $out);
// 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20
```

If you want to print all the keys too, then you could use this:

```php
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function ($v, $k) use (&$out) {
        $out[] = $k; // here you could check, if you want to add the $k (array key) to the output.
        $out[] = $v;
    }
);
```

Comment: I think both solutions are missing the number 9 and 16.

Answer (score -1):

Using Print_r() The print_r function is used to return an array in a human readable form in the PHP programming language. The print_r function is used to return an array in a human readable form in the PHP programming language. Menu. Home. Print_r() PHP Function. Search.

When displaying to screen or presentation media, programmer normally uses print_r () function to display the complete data of the array in a way that’s readable by humans. In order to write the content and data of array to the file, we can use the print_r () or var_export () functions to return the output instead of printing it.